# webpack-dev-server proxy GET request doesn't work, only POST

Tags: php, webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server

My webpack dev server is running on:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

My backend (API) is running on:

```
http://localhost/ (Apache server, PHP)
```

Webpack devserver proxy config:

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      target: 'http://localhost',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api': '/project-time-management/public/api/'
      },
      secure: false,
      changeOrigin: true
    }
  },
  historyApiFallback: true
}
```

When I try to call `/api/getUserProjects.php` from my React app using POST, everything is ok, JSON response is sent to browser as expected:

[image: json response from backend]

But when I try to call the same API using GET method, proxy doesn't work. Actually it works but not way I expected. Response is probably handled by Express server (webpack), PHP file is not intrepreted and whole content of the file is sent as response see images bellow.

[image: json response from express]

[image: response preview]

Am I missing some configuration or some headers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't.